# AJAX request in Laravel and ASCII response issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, laravel

I have a Laravel application that utilizes AJAX request quite a lot.

In one of these request I have to respond the AJAX request with JSON of persian letters (non-Latin) characters.

Traditional PHP has solved the problem for me with using this content type:

"application/json; charse=utf-8"

And it works.

But in Laravel it sends ASCII version of persian letters, something like this:

```
46 \u0646\u0645\u0648\u0646\u0647 \u0645\u062a\u0646 \u0646\u0645\u0648\u0646\u0647 \u0645\u062a\u0646 \u0646\u0645\u0648\u0646\u0647 \u0645\u062a\u0646 \u0646\u0645\u0648\u0646\u0647 \u0645\u062a\u0646 \u0646\u0645\
```

I cannot figure out the solution in the Laravel.

I send it like this in my view in Laravel:

```
$.ajax({
                   url : "<?php echo url("/ajax"); ?>",
                   data : { id : $(this).find("input[type='hidden']").val()},
                    cache : 'no-cache',
                    type : 'POST',
                    success : function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                });
```

And the the router:

```
Route::post("ajax", function(){
    header("ContentType=application/json; charset=utf-8");
    $res = Image::find(Req::id())->toArray();
    echo json_encode($res);
});
```

And the result is the ASCII characters printed above.

What should I do? One of the problem I guess is that in Laravel many things happen till the interpreter reaches the router and thus setting a header might need some configuration or trick or else.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to return the json using the response class.

```
Route::post('ajax', function()
{
    $headers = array(
        'ContentType' => 'application/json',
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
    );

    $res = Image::find(Req::id());

    return Response::json($res, 200, $headers);
});
```